# How can i set onClickListener and onTouchListenere Both on View Class in android

Tags: android, onclick

How can i set onClickListener and onTouchListenere Both on View Class in android?

my code:

```
package com.example.circledemo.second;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Dialog; import android.content.Context; import android.graphics.Bitmap; import android.graphics.Canvas; import android.graphics.Color; import android.graphics.Paint; import android.graphics.Path; import android.graphics.RectF; import android.view.MotionEvent; import android.view.View; import android.view.Window; import android.widget.ImageView; import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.circledemo.R;

public class SecondTCanvas extends View {

    public Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);  Context contextData;    int layoutWidth, layoutHeight;

    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

    public SecondTCanvas(Context context, float[] values, int width, int height) {      super(context);         contextData = context;      layoutHeight = height;      layoutWidth = width;

        System.out.println("===  Layout .... Width : " + layoutWidth + "  Height : " + layoutHeight);       }

    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);        c.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);       buildDrawingCache(true);        canvasBitmap = getDrawingCache(true);   }

    @Override   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {             // Get x and y coordinates of where the finger touched          int pixelX = (int) (Math.floor(event.getX()));          int pixelY = (int) (Math.floor(event.getY()));

            if (canvasBitmap != null) {             }


            invalidate();       }

        // If the finger is off the screen      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {           // alphaIndex = -1; //This is a flag to reset the view alphas to            // normal           invalidate();       }

        return true;

        // return super.onTouchEvent(event);    }


}
```

Comment: please explain your qu

Answer (score 1):

While using OnTouchListner  use **return False** now you can handle the click in click listner.

Comment: main thing i have done in my View class is just detect the color code on touch and open a my custom dialog then how can i close that dialog when touch or click on Close Image reside in the custom dialog